# Как считать json в select?

Tags: javascript, json

Есть json файлы, сначала считываю их php файлом, потом скриптом пытаюсь перенести эти данные в select список, но где-то ошибка. Скрипт писал не сам, а пытаюсь переделать тот что работал с БД.

Пример работающего скрипта:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var url = 'get_regions.php';

        $.get(
            url,
            "country_id=" + "3159",
            function (result) {
                if (result.type == 'error') {
                    alert('error');
                    return(false);
                }
                else {
                    var options = ''; 

                    $(result.regions).each(function() {
                        options += '<option value="' + $(this).attr('region_id') + '">' + $(this).attr('name') + '</option>';
                    });

                    $('#region_id').html('<option value="0">- выберите регион -</option>'+options);
                    $('#region_id').attr('disabled', false);
                    $('#city_id').html('<option>- выберите город -</option>');
                    $('#city_id').attr('disabled', true);   

                }
            },
            "json"

    );
```

пример структуры с которой работает:

```
Array
(
    [regions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Москва и Московская обл.
                    [region_id] => 4312
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Санкт-Петербург и область
                    [region_id] => 4925
                )
```

Мне же нужно прочитать вот такую структуру

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01
            [1] => Адыгея
            [2] => 106
            [3] => 385000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 02
            [1] => Башкортостан
            [2] => 106
            [3] => 452000
        )
```

Пробовал сменить атрибуты, но толку не принесло

```
options += '<option value="' + $(this).attr('0') + '">' + $(this).attr('1') + '</option>';
```

насколько понимаю, загвоздка в этой строке $(result.regions) но как считать массив если у него нет ключа, точнее ключ 0 если правильно понял

Comment: Причем тут java?

Comment: Java и JavaScript - это разные языки, у которых общего только 4 буквы в названии.

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, можно так:

```js
let json = [{
  'region_id':'123',
  'name':'Город'
},
 {
  'region_id':'321',
  'name':'Город2'
},
{
  'region_id':'555',
  'name':'Город3'
}];

json.forEach((item)=>{
  $('#sel').append('<option value="'+item.region_id +'">'+item.name +'</option>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="sel"></select>
```